# How to fix Sprinkles in rendering?

Tags: modeling, rendering, particles

Just started out Blender, and as my first project, I made Blender Guru's donuts. The problem is, when I go rendering, there are A MASSIVE amount of sprinkles, quite different from the Viewport. Here are some screenshots:

[image: Rendered]

[image: Viewport]

You can find the file [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6407/)!
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enabled *Interpolated* children in the particle settings, which means every sprinkle will spawn new sprinkles. If you set children to *None* and activate *Show Emitter* to render both sprinkles and the icing it will look just like in the viewport.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks. But now I have another problem, the icing isn't showing anymore

Comment: @Jojo you need to enable *Show Emitter*.